# How to analyze the heap dump using jhat

Tags: java, heap-dump, jhat

I ran the jhat on the heap dump, it has generated the reports. How do i use the report to analyze the heap.I couldn't understand completely other than the instance count. Is there any references or case studies on that.
In short, i need to proceed furthur, How can i?

Also what is object query language.

Comment: Finally settled with Eclipse Memory Analyzer, which gives almost everything we can get from the dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally settled with Eclipse Memory Analyzer, which gives almost everything we can get from the dump

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the [documentation for JHAT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jhat.html)? It details the various types of queries that can be performed using the heap analysis tool.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that hat is an older version and i can refer that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [object query language](http://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/querying_java_heap_with_oql) which is a part of JHAT.See which object's are prominent in memory at the time of heap dump and look up in the code if you can reduce unwanted object creation.

Also have look at this blog on [how to fix memory leaks.](http://olex.openlogic.com/wazi/2009/how-to-fix-memory-leaks-in-java/)

Comment: Thank you Emil, Let me go through the links.